# Python tkinter Checkbutton not appearing selected in Topframe window

Tags: python, button, tkinter, toplevel

When programming with tkinter I have found a very strange behaviour of the Checkbutton widget. I have re-created the bug with the code below:

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *

def displayWelcomeScreen(root):
    root2 = Toplevel(root)
    root2.geometry('600x380')
    root2.focus_set()

    Checked = IntVar()
    CheckButton1 = Checkbutton(root2, variable=Checked)
    CheckButton1.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor=CENTER)
    CheckButton1.select()

    # Create a dummy button that makes the Checkbutton appear checked to the user
    #Button(root2, command= lambda event: Checked.get())

root = Tk()
root.geometry('700x400')
displayWelcomeScreen(root)
root.mainloop()
```

When a new window is created with `Toplevel(root)` and I put a Checkbutton inside it, it does not appear checked to the user even though I use the `.select()` method.

However, when I create a dummy button whose command mentions the IntVar associated with my Checkbutton, somehow it is initialised as checked properly. It's almost as if the compiler checks whether the Checkbutton will be useful and decides based on that whether it will display it as selected or not.

EDIT: The Checkbutton is definitely checked under the hood because if I run `print(Checked.get())` before and after the `CheckButton1.select()` command, the value is changed, it just doesn't appear to the user.

Does anyone know why this happens?

EDIT 2: Thanks to jasonharper's explanation, I have added the line `CheckButton1.intvar = Checked` and it worked without needing the dummy button. When the function went out of scope, the Checked variable got lost so the Checkbutton had nowhere to store its state, therefore we needed to keep a reference to it so it didn't disappear.

Comment: The `IntVar` associated with your Checkbutton was only referred to via a local variable, and therefore vanished at the end of the function - thus leaving the Checkbutton with nowhere to store its state.  It's the same basic issue as Tkinter images disappearing if you didn't store a reference to them somewhere.

Comment: That makes sense! I added a 'intvar' attribute to my CheckButton1 and it worked. Thank you!